# VBA - Reference a cells range inside a table

Tags: vba, range

I want to use WorkSheetFunction.Match to find the value 0.002 value in the range compressed between two cells of a table named "Table". Here are the refferences of the cells.

`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("Table").Cells(1,1)` to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("Table").Cells(10,1)`

I would like to write something like this:

`WorkSheetFunction.Match(0.002, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("Table").Cells(1,1) : ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("Table").Cells(10,1))`

How can I make this work?

I tried

`WorkSheetFunction.Match(0.002, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("Table").Cells(1,1) : ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("Table").Cells(10,1))`

Comment: Is your Table a ListObject?   There are methods for referencing ranges within ListObjects.  For example see - https://exceloffthegrid.com/vba-excel-tables-code/

Comment: If it's not a structured table, have you excluded the headers from the `Table` range? Does the `Table` range contain only `10` rows? What are you planning to do with the resulting row? Please share more code so we can understand what you're trying to do.